Amplify - Auth and Data consoles data not up-to-date with my Xcode project
It is my first time using AWS Amplify. I have setup amplify (gen 2) authentication and data with my Swift project, and the AWS amplify console clearly shows my models and auth being available. However, despite successfully performing CRUD operations or creating new users in the project, both auth and data consoles show "no records to display". Whenever I sign in or CRUD the data everything happens successfully. Why is the console not up-to-date?
Could it be that right now I am using the sandbox and these changes are not officially saved?
Additionally, when I try to create a user manually in auth console and it appears when I attempt to login using my project UI, it says no user found with such creds.
